# Why is SharePoint 2013 incredibly slow to load after setting enableSessionState to true?

Tags: session, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, session-state

We are migrating various solutions (some all SharePoint, some built with .NET) from SharePoint 2007 to 2013.  It has been challenging to say the least.  However, today a .NET application needed enableSessionState set to true.  We already have session working (on a SQL Server, we have multiple WFE) and everything has been going fine.  However, after setting the value to true, the entire site, almost every application, slowed to a crawl and basically became non-functional.  Has anyone out there heard of something like this happening?  If so, what was the resolution?

Also, I've been looking, but I cannot find exactly what happens to the system when that particular value is set to true.  I know that pages can access session as a result, but what happens to the site/SharePoint when you set the value to true and save the web.config?

Comment: I would check the ULS logs and Event Logs on the servers for any errors.  Then check running processes for high cpu and memory usage.

Comment: Have you configured the rest of SharePoint to enable ASP SessionState? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607857.aspx